# Tkinter memory error: open CV video stops after a few seconds

Tags: python, tkinter, memory-management, opencv

I'm pretty new to coding and I ran into a problem trying to visualize a video using Open CV and Tkinter.
I'm building a GUI in which the frames captured by an esp32cam can be visualized accessing them through a webserver and then a photo can be taken. Also, there are buttons to control the movement of a robot by sending chars to the Arduino.

The thing is, after about 40 seconds the image freezes and I get:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
MemoryError
```

**The part of the code involving open cv and the video is:**

```
def visualize_video():
    def take_picture(event=""):
        now = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") 
        image_name = f"img{now}.jpg" 
        cv2.imwrite(image_name, img)
            
    imgResponse = urllib.request.urlopen (url) 
    imgNp = np.array(bytearray(imgResponse.read()),dtype=np.uint8)
    img = cv2.imdecode (imgNp, 1) 
    img = cv2.rotate(img, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE) 
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) 
        
    vid = Image.fromarray(img) 
    video = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=vid) 
    video_label = Label(window) 
    video_label.grid(row=1, column=0, rowspan=5, columnspan=2, padx=10)
    video_label.configure(image=video) 
    video_label.image = video
    video_label.after(10, visualize_video) 

    bpicture = tk.Button(window, text="Take picture", command=take_picture, bg='red3', fg='gray7', font=('Comic Sans MS', 14))
    bpicture.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=10, columnspan=2) 
    window.bind("<space>", take_picture)
```

and the whole program is as follows:

```
import serial
import time
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils
import urllib.request

window = tk.Tk()
window.configure(background='ivory3')
window.geometry('1080x720')
window.title('Robot Explorador - PYTHON GUI')

url = 'http://192.168.1.53/cam-res.jpg'

ArduinoUNO = serial.Serial(port='COM4', baudrate=9600, bytesize=8)

def visualize_video():
    def take_picture(event=""):
        now = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") 
        image_name = f"img{now}.jpg" 
        cv2.imwrite(image_name, img)
            
    imgResponse = urllib.request.urlopen (url) 
    imgNp = np.array(bytearray(imgResponse.read()),dtype=np.uint8)
    img = cv2.imdecode (imgNp, 1) 
    img = cv2.rotate(img, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE) 
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) 
        
    vid = Image.fromarray(img) 
    video = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=vid) 
    video_label = Label(window) 
    video_label.grid(row=1, column=0, rowspan=5, columnspan=2, padx=10)
    video_label.configure(image=video) 
    video_label.image = video
    video_label.after(10, visualize_video) 

    bpicture = tk.Button(window, text="Take picture", command=take_picture, bg='red3', fg='gray7', font=('Comic Sans MS', 14))
    bpicture.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=10, columnspan=2) 
    window.bind("<space>", take_picture) 
    
def robot_control():
    
    showMenu = '''    ****************************************
    ------------CONTROL DEL ROBOT-------------
    ****************************************
    ------------------- CAMARA -------------------
    barra espaciadora -> tomar foto
    i -> girar 15 grados a la IZQUIERDA             
    o -> CENTRAR camara                             
    p -> girar 15 grados a la DERECHA               
    ****************************************
    ----------------- DIRECCION ------------------
    d -> girar a la DERECHA              
    a -> girar a la IZQUIERDA              
    w -> hacia ADELANTE                 
    c -> DETENERSE                      
    s -> REVERSA                        
    ****************************************
    esc -> SALIR                          
    ****************************************\n'''
    
    def c_izquierda(event=""):
        ArduinoUNO.write('i'.encode('ascii'))
        label_orden.configure(text='camara hacia la IZQUIERDA')
        
    def c_centrar(event=""):
        ArduinoUNO.write('o'.encode('ascii'))
        label_orden.configure(text='CENTRAR camara')
        
    def c_derecha(event=""):
        ArduinoUNO.write('p'.encode('ascii'))
        label_orden.configure(text='camara hacia la DERECHA')

    def m_derecha(event=""):
        ArduinoUNO.write('d'.encode('ascii'))
        label_orden.configure(text='girar a la DERECHA')
        
    def m_izquierda(event=""):
        ArduinoUNO.write('a'.encode('ascii'))
        label_orden.configure(text='girar a la IZQUIERDA')
        
    def m_adelante(event=""):
        ArduinoUNO.write('w'.encode('ascii'))
        label_orden.configure(text='hacia ADELANTE')
                
    def m_reversa(event=""):
        ArduinoUNO.write('s'.encode('ascii'))
        label_orden.configure(text='REVERSA')
        
    def m_stop(event=""):
        ArduinoUNO.write('c'.encode('ascii'))
        label_orden.configure(text='DETENERSE')
        
    def salir(event=""):
        ArduinoUNO.write('x'.encode('ascii'))
        window.destroy()
        window.destroy()
        ArduinoUNO.close()
        label_orden.configure(text='saliendo...')
    
    image_save = Label(window, text = 'imagen guardada en:', font=('Calibri', 11), justify=LEFT)  
    image_save.grid(row=7, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='NE') 
    image_path = Label(window, text='D:\Coding', font=('Calibri', 11), justify=LEFT)
    image_path.grid(row=7, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='NW')

    label_instrucciones = Label(window, text = showMenu, font=('Comic Sans MS', 13), justify=LEFT)
    label_instrucciones.grid(row=1, column=2, rowspan=5, padx=10)
    
    label_orden = Label(window, text = 'esperando instrucciones...', font=('Courier New', 11), justify=LEFT)
    label_orden.grid(row=7, column=2, sticky=N)
    
    b1 = tk.Button(window, text="IZQUIERDA", command=c_izquierda, bg='cadet blue', fg='gray7', font=('Comic Sans MS', 14))
    b2 = tk.Button(window, text="CENTRAR", command=c_centrar, bg='cadet blue', fg='gray7', font=('Comic Sans MS', 14))
    b3 = tk.Button(window, text="DERECHA", command=c_derecha, bg='cadet blue', fg='gray7', font=('Comic Sans MS', 14))

    b4 = tk.Button(window, text="DERECHA", command=m_derecha, bg='SpringGreen3', fg='gray7', font=('Comic Sans MS', 14))
    b5 = tk.Button(window, text="ADELANTE", command=m_adelante, bg='SpringGreen3', fg='gray7', font=('Comic Sans MS', 14))
    b6 = tk.Button(window, text="IZQUIERDA", command=m_izquierda, bg='SpringGreen3', fg='gray7', font=('Comic Sans MS', 14))
    b7 = tk.Button(window, text="REVERSA", command=m_reversa, bg='SpringGreen3', fg='gray7', font=('Comic Sans MS', 14))
    b8 = tk.Button(window, text="STOP", command=m_stop, bg='SpringGreen3', fg='gray7', font=('Comic Sans MS', 14))
    b9 = tk.Button(window, text="SALIR", command=salir, bg='firebrick3', fg='gray7', font=('Comic Sans MS', 14)) 

    
    b1.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=5, pady=10)
    b2.grid(row=1, column=4, padx=5, pady=10)
    b3.grid(row=1, column=5, padx=5, pady=10)

    b4.grid(row=3, column=5, padx=5, pady=10, sticky=W)
    b5.grid(row=2, column=4, padx=5, pady=10, sticky=S)
    b6.grid(row=3, column=3, padx=5, pady=10, sticky=E)
    b7.grid(row=4, column=4, padx=5, pady=10, sticky=N)
    b8.grid(row=5, column=4, padx=5, pady=10, sticky=N)
    b9.grid(row=6, column=4, padx=5, pady=10, sticky=N)
    
    window.bind("e", c_izquierda)
    window.bind("r", c_centrar)
    window.bind("f", c_derecha)
    window.bind("d", m_derecha)
    window.bind("w", m_adelante)
    window.bind("a", m_izquierda)
    window.bind("s", m_reversa)
    window.bind("c", m_stop)
    window.bind("<Escape>", salir)

    window.mainloop()

time.sleep(.1)
visualize_video()
robot_control()
```

This is for my graduation project at school, any help would be very much appreciated and referenced.

Comment: You're creating a brand-new Label each time, to display the new PhotoImage - and just pile it on top of all the previous Labels.  Your program's memory use will therefore grow without bound.  You want a single Label, and just change the image it displays on each frame.

Comment: Please reduce the code down to a [mcve]. I'm guessing a lot of  the code you posted is not necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you both @jasonharper and Bryan Oakley, I will take into account reducing my code down to a minimal reproducible example next time as you already have solved my problem.